# jQuery animate background-size property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<a class="home-page" href="http://google.com">  
    <section class="col left">
        <div class="opacity-overlay"></div>
        <div class="description">
            <img src="img/mobile-apps.png" alt="Mobile Application Design and Development"><br>
            <h1 class="homepage">
                Mobile Application <br>
                Design &amp; Development
            </h1>
            <p class="homepage">
                (iOS — Android — Windows)
            </p>
            <h1 class="view">View Projects</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
</a>
```

And the CSS:

```
section.col {
    width:33%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
}
section.left {
    background: url(../img/left-col-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center ; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I need to animate the ZOOM effect on the background image when the `section` is in `:hover`. I've tried to use CSS transition but it animates my entire content, not just the background image. So I decided to try jQuery. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.col').mouseenter(function(e) {
        $(this).animate({
            "background-size":"120%"
        }, 3000 );
    }).mouseleave(function(e) {
        $(this).animate({
            "background-size":"100%"
        }, 3000 );
    });
});
```

This doesn't really do the trick as it start animation as if my background was 0% so it doesn't zoom in from the `cover` state but actually makes it disappear and then zooms to 120%. Any thoughts?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72zsnzbd/) example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is a CSS only solution

```
section.left {
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72385383/left-col-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
section.left:hover {
    -webkit-background-size: 120%;
    -moz-background-size: 120%;
    -o-background-size: 120%;
    background-size: 120%;}
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/72zsnzbd/8/)**

**EDIT** *jQuery Solution*

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".col").css({"background-size":"100%"})
        $('.col').mouseenter(function(e) {
            $(this).animate({
                "background-size":"120%"
            }, 3000 );
        }).mouseleave(function(e) {
            $(this).animate({
                "background-size":"100%"
            }, 3000 );
        });
    });
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/72zsnzbd/27/)**

Comment: I tried this before and am trying it now again - but i don't get the animation, just a jump. Any idea why?

Comment: Which browser are you on btw?

Comment: testing in latest chrome and mozilla

Comment: See the added jQuery Solution.

Comment: also, when on narrow screen, i get a glitch where my top and bottom blank out (image compresses in): http://grab.by/F0hm

Comment: Tried the jQuery as well, but the bg images don't `cover`... see screenshot of top area: http://grab.by/F0hq

Comment: 'cover' and  '100%' are not the same thing